# Is there a way to automatically use triangular elements in ToElementMesh

Tags: finite-element-method, mesh, discretization

I have some simple code to generate a mesh over a rectangle.

```
(* Generic Clear All *)
ClearAll["Global`*"];

(* Import the Mathematica Finite Element Model library *)
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];

(* Generate an element mesh for a 13 [m] \[Times] 6 [m] region *)
ToElementMesh[Rectangle[{-6.5,0},{6.5,6}]]["Wireframe"]
```

When I run this code, it generates a mesh with rectangular elements.  I would like the mesh generator to use triangular elements.  It appears that I can lay this out manually and use the "MeshElements" option. This would require that I enter a list of individual coordinates for each triangular element.

Is there a way to automatically generate a grid with Triangular elements instead of rectangular elements?

Comment: This is discussed in the [docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/ref/ToElementMesh.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add the option `"MeshElementType" -> TriangleElement`:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
ToElementMesh[Rectangle[{-6.5, 0}, {6.5, 6}],
  "MeshElementType" -> TriangleElement
  ]["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

Comment: I also noticed that if you use an ImplicitRegion (instead of a Rectangle), ToElementMesh will default to a Triangular element.